# Login and logout issue within zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, doctrine

I am working on PHP with zend framework, there are two modules in the project i.e Front end(**simple user**) and Back end(**Admin**). Both have the login forms and both have their own authentication adapter to login as well as their own layout. For DB handling I am using Doctrine ORM. There is a one user table and two inherited tables from user (i.e simple user and admin).

Now  the issue is that when I login from admin module, simple user module is automatically login and vise versa.  Same thing happens at logout time. So Please guide me guys what to do.As the is no option to use different tables for two modules.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807174/refactoring-a-zend-auth-implementation

Answer (score 1):

You login from two different login pages, to two different actions, right? There should be either

- a different receiving action; or
- something else, like a `<input type="hidden" name="login_as_admin" value="1" />` in the admin form

You need to make **the input parameters different in the two cases**, so you can handle them separately. If I'm off, you need to show some code to prove me wrong ;)